# Extract file attachment from Outlook VCALENDAR ics event file

Tags: python, base64, icalendar

I received an email with an ics event attachment, which I [imported](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37118) into Google Calendar but then found out it lost the attachment. The file was ~3MB, and I can see a base64 encoded docx file in the ATTACH component:

```
$ cat event.ics | head -n 24
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 16.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Eastern Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16011104T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=1SU;BYMONTH=11
TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
TZOFFSETTO:-0500
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:16010311T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYDAY=2SU;BYMONTH=3
TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
TZOFFSETTO:-0400
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTACH;ENCODING=BASE64;VALUE=BINARY;X-FILENAME="Instructions.docx":UEsDBBQABgA
    AAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

How can I extract this attachment in Python or Bash?

Answer (score 0):

I found a [icalendar pypi module](https://github.com/collective/icalendar) that seemed to work:

```
apt-get install python3-venv
cd /tmp
python3 -m venv ical
source ./ical/bin/activate

pip install icalendar

python << SCRIPTMARKER
from icalendar import Calendar, Event
import base64
import io

g = open('/tmp/event.ics','rb') # read ics
gcal = Calendar.from_ical(g.read())

for component in gcal.walk():
    print(component.name)
    if component.name == "VEVENT":
        b64 = component.get('attach')
        data = base64.b64decode(b64)
        f = open('/tmp/event.docx','wb') # write binary attachment
        f.write(data)
        print(f)
        f.close()

g.close()
SCRIPTMARKER

# Results after running the above:
VCALENDAR
VTIMEZONE
STANDARD
DAYLIGHT
VEVENT
<_io.BufferedWriter name='/tmp/event.docx'>
VALARM
```

I could then upload the event.docx file to Google Drive and open it there.